# Quintic Equation

Tags: polynomials, factoring, quintics

I got problem written as this,

> For solvable quintic
> $$
> \frac{32}{7} \cos^5 x - \frac{32}{7}\cos^3 x-\frac47 \cos^2 x + \frac{22}{7}\cos x - 1 = 0,
> $$
> show that one of the cosine function is $\cos x = 1/2$.

this is a 5th degree polynomials, also called by quintic equation. I tried to read explanation in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function) but can't quite find the answer. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is even asking. (Along the same lines, the fact that the question is not grammatical is a red flag to me, and I would question following that learning source too closely). But one possible interpretation would be to show that a value of $x$ such that $\cos x = 1/2$ gives one root.

Comment: I think the interpretation that davidlowryduda offered is correct. You can check that if $\cos x = 1/2$, the equation holds.

Comment: Neither me also understand what the question about haha, my lecturer won't even read my message, but maybe can we find some roots for the quintic equation given? neglecting the last line.

Comment: "Solvable" is usually used for quintic (and higher degree) equations that are irreducible and yet solvable with radicals. If you have a rational root the equation is "reducible" rather than "solvable". One reason for this distinction is that relationships derived for "solvable" quintics do not generally apply to "reducible" ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $2\cos{x}=t$.

Thus, we need to solve
$$t^5-4t^3-t^2+11t-7=0$$ or
$$t^5-t^4+t^4-t^3-3t^3+3t^2-4t^2+4t+7t-7=0$$ or
$$(t-1)(t^4+t^3-3t^2-4t+7)=0$$ and since by AM-GM
$$t^4+t^3-3t^2-4t+7=(t^4+3-4t)+\left(2\cdot\frac{t^3}{2}+4-3t^2\right)\geq$$
$$\geq4\sqrt[4]{t^4\cdot1^3}-4t+3\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{t^3}{2}\right)^2\cdot4}-3t^2=4(|t|-t)>0,$$
we obtain $t=1$ and $\cos{x}=\frac{1}{2}$ only.

Comment: @Deepak Because I want to show that it's an unique real root.

Comment: To answer the question itself, all you need is to substitute $\cos x = \frac12$ and it's a trivial solution. I guess you're answering the question the OP asked in his comment.

Comment: @MichaelRozenburg I don't see where the question asked for that detail (unique real root).

Comment: @Deepak  Yes I saw it and it seems that just needs to solve this equation with the hint.